# Using Plugs for specific actions in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I use a plug to specific actions on phoenix. The scenario being  want to use a plug for a certain actions, or  the opposite, **not** want to use the plug in a certain actions

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As specified in docs  [plugs controller docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/plug.html#controller-plugs), we can use guard clauses

> plug/2 supports guards, allowing a developer to configure a plug to only run in some particular action

```
plug :log_message, "before show and edit" when action in [:show, :edit]
plug :log_message, "before all but index" when not action in [:index]
# or
plug :log_message, "before all but index" when action not in [:index]
```

> The first plug will run only when action is show or edit. The second plug will always run, except for the index action.

I found this after bit of searching at this [issue](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/204). Which lead me to the docs. Hope it helps someone